# How do I make my muscles harder/firmer?

Tags: strength, strength-training, bodyweight-exercises

I'm into bodyweight training and it's worked better for me than the gym.
I follow the Convict Conditioning program and it's working well for me so far.

I'm noticing progress every time I work out so I think I'm on the right track... however, my muscles are quite soft, especially my pecs.
I'm kind of happy with the firmness in my arms and legs, at least I'm noticing improvement in firmness and strength.
Abs are soft but I'm noticing improvement in firmness.

My pecs are getting stronger but I find them extremely soft.

I'm naturally thin, i.e. I find it harder to gain weight than losing weight. I'm not too thin either so I'm quite happy with my weight. So I guess high body fat is probably not a reason for my soft pecs.

1) How can I get them firmer?
2) Are firmer muscles necessarily healthier? I read somewhere that firmer muscles mean that they're not relaxed.

I'm not comfortable with protein shakes or other products so I don't have them.

Answer (score 2):

As far as getting firmer or more toned muscles, it's ALL about how much body fat you have; the less body fat, the more lean and toned/defined your muscles will be. I would recommend eating slightly less for a couple days to a week just to see if you like the results. Also pectoral specific lifts such as bench, dips and flies would help too. try to be getting in at least two thirds or so of your body weight in protein per day. AT LEAST. You'll be more fit, and one thing i know for damn sure is muscle burns fat much faster than fat burns fat. In other words you'll notice you can eat more without having to worry much about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right answer, muscles themselves can not be more or less firm, you have to distinguish between the "muscles" you see from the outside, and the layer of fat and muscle that is actually there. Firm "muscles" = developed muscles and thin layer of fat. I'd like to add that eating 2/3 of your body weight in protein is most likely deadly though ;-)

Comment: he probably meant grams...